# Gradiant and angle visualisation of an image with HOGDescriptor (OpenCV for Android)

Tags: android, windows, opencv

I try to visualize the gradiants and angles of an image which computed by the HOGDescriptor of the OpenCV Lib for Android. At the begin i have an 3 channel image Mat() with 8 bit unsigned int (CV_8UC3). The result of the computation is a MAT() (CV_32FC2) of the gradiants and a Mat() (CV_8UC2) of the angles. How can i visualize this results? What represent the values? Why have the angle Mat() 2 channels? Are the 2 channels of the gradiant Mat() the x and y component of the gradiant? I cant find documentation of the computeGradiant-Method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HOG descriptor is an histogram of oriented gradient: it is an histogram where each bin reprezent the vote for gradient in corresponding orientation.
In order to compute this descriptor, you should first convert you 3 channels color image into a grayscale image

```
cv::cvtColor(CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

The result of "ComputeGradient" method is for exemple two images (same size as the original): x-component and y-component.
You should then be able to compute for each pixel the gradient magnitude and orientation.

```
mag=sqrt(x*x+y*y)
alpha=atan(y/x)
```

Then you can fill you histogram. Note that HOG descritpor is computed by blocks and cells. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) for more detail.

Comment: The result of computeGradient are really 2 images which named: grad and angle. The grad Mat() have 2 channels. I think this represent 1 chennel for x-component and 1 channel y-component of each pixel. Than i can compute the magnitude with "mag=sqrt(x*x+y*y)", but why 2 channel for the angle Mat()? If this Mat() contains the angles, 1 channel was enough?

Comment: Where can I find your computeGradient function ? CV_32FC1 is enough for angles.

Comment: You can find the "computeGradient": http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/structcv_1_1_h_o_g_descriptor.html#a5ce15ef09b0eb7d0ecfd7f2eb353df83 And for Android: http://ngocdaothanh.github.com/opencv_android_javadoc/index.html?overview-tree.html

Comment: computeGradient (const Mat &img, CV_OUT Mat &grad, CV_OUT Mat &angleOfs, Size paddingTL=Size(), Size paddingBR=Size()) const : angleIfs's type is CV_UC2. It reprezent [0..nbins-1] quantized gradient orientation for first channel.